# ReactJS component height '100%'

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to set my immediate child node of `<div id='root'>` to be `height: 100%`, however I realized react is adding an extra layer of react node preventing the child's `height: 100%` from working. Example below:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="root"> <== root node is height:100%, still good here
  <div data-reactid=".0"> <== added by react? broke the child height
    <div data-reactid=".0.$/=10" style="height: 100%; background-color: gray;"> <== child can't get 100% height of #root because of the empty div wrapping it
```

My JSX code is not adding this `data-reactid='.0'` wrapper div, so I don't have control over the styles. So the question here is, how do I have control over this wrapper div, or how do I achieve `height:100%` using some other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: React doesnot add the wrapper div for sure ,Any fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

the wrapper div should be in your code, something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div> // the wrapper div
            <div style={{ height: "100%", "background-color": "gray" }}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  height:100%
}

#root > div {
  height:100%
}
```

This will apply width:100% to all direct div child nodes of #root.

Answer (score 0):

```
#root > div {
  height:100%;
}
```